# Build custom MIB? SNMP4j

Tags: snmp, snmp4j, mib

I would like to build a custom MIB in which I define some useful objects that can be accessed and managed by others (clients)..
I've been googling  this for hours now without finding any interesting documentation about that..

So first of all, is is possible to build custom MIB? if yes, is there any interesting web sites to deal with this issue?  would be really grateful if you answer me, so that I can switch to other solutions if SNMP4j is not appropriate for my application..

Cheers,

Marie

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a toolset to create a SNMP agent (command responder) with SNMP4J(-Agent) then why not using AGENT++ [MIB Designer](http://www.mibdesigner.com) to define the MIB specification and then [AgenPro](http://agentpp.com) to simulate the agent (based on SNMP4J-Agent) and generate the stub code for SNMP4J-Agent.

You will get a running (although no yet instrumented) agent within a few minutes without the risk of making errors while transferring the MIB design to the agent code.

With the simulation agent you may try the MIB design before you generate the code.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to build code responding on *'your own MIB*'.

**First of all the vocabulary** (it will help to google): the deamon (or service) waiting on an SNMP port (161) is called *Agent*. If I understand you want that this agent gives responses on new MIBs (yours). For this you need to create a *Proxy Agent* for you agent.

**Solutions** : Proxy Agents are not so standard.

1. If you are able to rebuild your agent (Net-SNMP) you can build in the code for your MIB. The kind of agent you can rebuild provide compilers that create skeltons code from MIB file. After that you can choose to load your code into the agent or in a separated module. See [TUT:Writing a MIB Module](http://www.net-snmp.org/wiki/index.php/TUT%3aWriting_a_MIB_Module).You can find something similary for Microsoft integrated SNMP agent (even if you can't rebuild the agent). It exists much commercial SNMP solutions that allows to build your own Agent.
2. It exist a standard to extend Agent which is called [AgentX](http://www.scguild.com/agentx/) (it's not talking about spy)

Now I let you googling with `build an agent with SNMP4j` or `build a proxy agent with SNMP4j`. As I can read "*The SNMP4J-Agent pure Java SNMP agent API adds command responder including notification originator and proxy forwarder support to the SNMP4J core API*" it sound promising.

Comment: Your answer is focused on building an agent rather than developing a custom MIB as requested by the questioner. Is there any tool which helps me build my MIB?

Comment: Yes, you can use [MG-SOFT Visual MIB Builder for Windows](http://www.mg-soft.si/builder.html?p1=products&p2=mgProductsNMA-SMI)